# Html input type time and Java Date object

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs

I have a Java date object. How it should be converted (I mean string presentation) to be displayed as `HTML`:

```
<input type='time' ng-model='myTimeFromServer'/>
```

`myTimeFromServer` in `ng-model` is String from server `new Date().toString()`
I need to use `input` because it is predefined value that user can change.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What format do _you_ want to see it in?

Comment: possible duplicate of [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5619202/converting-string-to-date-in-js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5619202/converting-string-to-date-in-js).  Try moment.js than relying on the native JS Date object.  The API [here](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) might give you an idea.

Comment: why dont use ``ng-init`` to display ``myTimeFromServer``?

Answer (score 1):

The java date object needs to be formatted to string in the format you want. Below is snippet of code to format date in format 'dd/MM/yyyy' using SimpleDateFormat.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
String formattedDate = sdf.format(new Date());
```

Comment: Thanks! But I need formatted string with time, not date

Comment: Please use format 'HH:mm:ss.SSS' to get time upto milliseconds from java date.

Answer (score 0):

Java Date's [toString](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html#toString()) only returns the date in yyyy-mm-dd format.
So if you need time you should use [getTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getTime()) instead and use Javascript [setTime](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_settime.asp) on the other side. Both handles milliseconds.